# Red alerts for machines in TIBCO admin

Tags: tibco

In TIBCO admin i am getting red status for some of the machines. I think the issue is with HAWK. Why i am getting these alerts ? Is it serious ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is Hawk that generates those alerts. Do you have any more detail for the alerts it's generating? Failing that, the most probable reason is that you aren't running the Hawk Agent on those machines or they are on another subnet, which can't be reached via RV.